# iPod touch resetting

Tags: ipod-touch

My ex husband bought our daughter an iPod touch and put everything under his email account so when she try's to text and stuff it goes to him. Is there a way to reset just the email to hers so she can talk with her friends in private. I would reset the whole thing but she has already bought a lot of music and we don't have iTunes or Internet on home computer.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough...

go into Settings -> iCloud and sign out of his account there. You may also have to do the same in the Message -> iMessage settings.

Once that is done you can use her email for the icloud and iMessage account.

If you do that and are still getting his messages use the Apple Support page for de-registering your account on that phone:

https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage